# how to generate WSDL stubs with Jakarta using Maven

Tags: web-services, wsdl, java-20

I need to generate java files from `.wsdl` file with jakarta.
I'm using java 20

I used jakarta dependency and below plugin and run `mvn clean install`

Here is a part of my `.wsdl` file

```
---

<wsdl:binding name="HexingWsServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:HexingWs">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="trans">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="rpc"/>
      <wsdl:input name="trans">
        <soap:body namespace="http://service.ws.tangdi/" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="transResponse">
        <soap:body namespace="http://service.ws.tangdi/" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="HexingWsService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:HexingWsServiceSoapBinding" name="HexingWsPort">
      <soap:address location="http://-------------------------"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
```

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <wsdlDirectory>Development/middle-ware/utility/src/main/resources/</wsdlDirectory>
                    <wsdlFiles>
                        <wsdlFile>hexingws.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                    </wsdlFiles>
                    <packageName>com.omo.robi.ThirdpartyRequest.webservice</packageName>
                    <sourceDestDir>
                        Development/middle-ware/utility/src/main/java/
                    </sourceDestDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

java files are not creating with this method.
I have a confusion in putting `<sourceDestDir>` and `<packageName>` attributes

I would like to know what is the mistake I have done here and are there any other methods to do this.

Is there a way to do this using Apache Axis

since I'm a newbie if someone can explain this step by step, it will be so helpful to me

Answer (score -1):

Below documentation and few modifications in pom.xml solved the issue.

Added jakarta dependencies in pom.

Added following plugin in pom.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.0.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <wsdlDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</wsdlDirectory>
    <packageName>com.baeldung.soap.ws.client</packageName>
    <sourceDestDir>
        ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/
    </sourceDestDir>
</configuration>
```

Change the values of

```
packageName
```

and

```
wsdlDirectory
```

properties according to your project.

Then run

```
mvn clean install
```

The generated classes can be found in the place as configured in the

```
packageName
```

property.

Use the compatible **versions** for your project.

Here I put the link to the document for further studying.

[link to document](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-wsdl-stubs)

hope this will help someone :)